# Why the method doesn't work, however the same algorithm in another method works?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq, return-value

I have a DB with Entity Framework, using a repository design pattern. There's a method in my repository which gets two inputs, an entity and an `IQuerable<Entity>` collection. The method algorithm should return another entity from the collection, based on the entity input (for the sake of simplicity imagine a dating app where the userA gets userB as a recommendation, based on userA's preferences).

I have a test class library for testing the repository, using nUnit and MOQ. I setup the mock correctly to return a fake user list. and then I tested the method.

Here is the twist. The unit test fails, because the repository method returns null. However if I copy and paste the algorithm right into the unit test it returns the correct data. What's wrong? How is that possible? In the below code I commented the right and wrong stuff...

Repository method:

```
public IUser SearchForDate(IUser entity, IQueryable<USERS> users)
{
        var userPartner = users.Where(x => x.Interested == entity.Male)
            .Where(x => x.MinAge < entity.Age)
            .Where(x => x.MaxAge > entity.Age)
            .Where(x => x.WantToDate == true).FirstOrDefault();

        return userPartner;
}
```

At setup:

```
this.userRepo.Setup(x => x.GetAllIUsers()).Returns(testUsers);
this.userRepo.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(testUsers2.AsQueryable());
IUserRepository Repo = this.userRepo.Object;
```

At unit test:

```
[TestCase("Andrew", "Angela")]
public void SearchForPartner_ReturnsTheCorrectPartner(string userName, string partnerName)
{
        //Assert - Act
        var users = Repo.GetAll();
        var userNeedsPartner = users.Single(x => x.Nickname == userName); //this return the correct user - Andrew
        var partner = Repo.SearchForDate(userNeedsPartner, Repo.GetAll()); //NOT GOOD, WHY????Even if I use users instead of Repo.GetAll() - this mothafucka returns null.

        var partnerForUser = Repo.GetAll().Where(x => x.Interested == userNeedsPartner.Male)
           .Where(x => x.MinAge < userNeedsPartner.Age)
           .Where(x => x.MaxAge > userNeedsPartner.Age)
           .Where(x => x.WantToDate == true).FirstOrDefault(); //GOOD, WHY??? - This returns the correct user - Angela

        //Arrange
        Assert.That(partner.Nickname, Is.EqualTo(partnerName)); //NULLReferenceException...
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you are testing? `Repo.SearchForDate` is mocked object's method that you did not setup... What exactly do you expect to happen on that line? (Note if you don't understand what's going on in some code it is good idea to have one statement per line, including all parameters computed first... And good naming like `MockedRepo` instead of `Repo` would greatly help)

Comment: Your code will not work if you consider it as mothafucka in your commets. That why I stopped reading anyways.

Comment: And what is `Repo.GetAll()`?

Comment: Think you are mocking `GetAllUsers()` but then using `GetAll()`

Comment: Sorry, ```GetAll()``` also setup in the ```SetUp()``` method. I haven't included it. I updated the question.

Comment: You are testing method of mocked object, instead you should test actual method of actual repository implementation.

Comment: The only reason I am using mock is to return a fake user list, instead of actual DB user list. The ```Repo``` is actually ```Mock<IUserRepository>().Object```, so it is an unmocked repository I believe. It worked with other projects before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I finally figured out a solution to this. As I declared my Mock as `private  Mock<IUserRepository> userRepo = new Mock<IUserRepository>();` and then declared a repository as `IUserRepository Repo = userRepo.Object;` so when I called the `Repo.SearchForDate(IUser entity, IQuerable<USERS> users);` method, it was returning null all the time, because Repo was just an interface without real implementation. So I decided to change the Mock's type from `IUserRepository` to `UserRepository` and boom... Suddenly it all started to working. Anyway, thanks guys for helping me out! :)